# Vimeo embed video is not playing when clicked

Tags: jquery, wordpress, vimeo-player, video-embedding

Hello on this website I have there is a overlay play button on image which when clicked will load vimeo video with and play it but here the problem is that the video does load but pauses automatically. Even though autoplay parameter is already present. The site in question is this.

https://transplant.tv/portfolio/sharing-schemes/

Is this because of chrome and other browsers policy which blocks autoplay of video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are some browser policy that doesn't allow you the autoplay vidos UNTIL there is no user interaction on the page. So basically, if you display a video on a button click, that will work with autoplay.

I tried to do the following a while ago and figured out that it works only if I did some interaction on the page (like click) before.

[Here](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/#:%7E:text=A%20feature%20policy%20allows%20developers,default%20on%20same%2Dorigin%20iframes.) is a detailed policy changes from Google.

Comment: Would have been useful if you had included any woraround for that or solution

Comment: Okay. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Szabii/gLhxszp6/21/) is a working fiddle that can explain everything you need to know about it with example. The point is that you have to do any interaction on the page before generating the video with autoplay attribute. So if you load a page and the video is in the DOM, it won't autoplay because you didn't do any interaction on the page before it's got generated.